# certificate authority generate my private key, Is safe?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

1. When I applied for a certificate, I found that the certificate authority gave me the private key and the certificate file together, but does this mean that the certificate authority already has my private key? Is this safe?
2. I want to know the certificate authority how to generate a private key? Is the keyword a random number or something?

Comment: By definition a private key is only private if only the entity using it has it, and noone else. The CA shouldn't, doesn't need to, and must not have it. Immediately revoke (make the CA revoke) the certificate, and do not use it. Use another CA or make sure you are the only one having a copy of the private key. As for 2, no it is not "random" numbers and it is more complicated than that there are multiple crypto algorithms family like RSA vs ECC. Besides your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Look at [su] instead probably.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally at the time of Enrolling Certificate, Private Key is generated in your computer's key store or in cryptographic device viz. smartcard or usb token connected to your computer. Private key then never comes out of cryptographic device.  The data (hash) to be signed or encrypted goes to chip in cryptographic device and signed or encrypted data is returned by the cryptographic device. Certifying Authority (CA) get the public key and some more information which he signs using CA's private key and returns you as Certificate.  The certificate get imported to cryptographic device (or your computers certificate store) to complete certificate enrollment process...

> the certificate authority already has my privatekey? Is this safe?

Single word answer is **NO.**

2. Private key is a random number generated by cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: Modulus and Exponent is only related to a specific family, like RSA and not all cases. Also saying "Lot of material available on SO and internet about this." without giving any hints on what to search for (like "RSA")  or some links, is not very helpful.